# Can Ping Server but no RDP nor File Sharing Sometimes

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

I am facing a really weird behavior with my server.
First, the Server is a Windows Server 2012 R2, it has no access to Internet for security reasons
When working fine, people on the LAN are connected to the Server and can see their shared folders and can connect using RDP to the server.

The problem is that today it is failing sometimes, i mean, i can't see the shared folders, neither connect using RDP.

I can ping the server always, ping never fails.

This problem started yesterday with two people, but when they reseted their PC they could connect sometimes, but now it's affecting to everybody.

We use mainly Windows 10 on our Pcs and some Windows 7

It's really weir and i don't understand a thing.

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after testing everything, it seems that somebody set his IP wrong making an IP conflict with the server,